MarkLogic Gradle error as it is unable to download the MarkLogic gradle Jar on Unix server

While trying to initialize Gradle build on Unix server I am getting Gradle error as it is unable to download the MarkLogic gradle Jar on  Unix server
Error details
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

Could not download ml-data-hub.jar (com.marklogix:ml-data-hub:5.4.2)
Could not get resource 'http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/marklogic/ml-data-hub/5.4.2/ml-data-hub-5.4.2.jar'.
> Could not GET 'http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/marklogic/ml-data-hub/5.4.2/ml-data-hub-5.4.2.jar'.
> sun.security.validator.'http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/marklogic/ml-data-hub/5.4.2/alidatorException: PKIX path building failed:sun.secirity.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certificate path to requested target

Same gradle configuration I did for other environment and its working fine .I am trying to configure the same on another environment and getting above error.
I have attached details error logs which I am getting while trying to initialize Gradle build 
Can you please help me on this.

Don't upload pictures of your monitor to demonstrate the output. Copy/paste the text.

That being said, it looks like your Java client doesn't trust the cert presented for your Nexus repo at https://repository.ntrs.com:8444/nexus

Thanks for your help. can I download the cert from browser and copy to cacerts under jre folder or is their any other way to add certificate to trusted store?
